# Where to get 1440 free cron jobs a day?

Tags: java, php, google-app-engine, cron

I'm making a program for my own use.
In this program, I need to set up cron job. The cron job should run every minute (24 hr * 60 mins = 1440 times). Thus, I'll need to set up a cron job with a frequency of 1 minute.

I think Google App Engine gives free cron job. But I'm very new to it. I downloaded the java SDK and read the document but understood nothing :( So, I can't use  Google App Engine.
Is here any other free service like Google app engine which but with easier inferface???

*All I want is a cron job with 1 minute frequency*

Please help/suggest me...
Thank you

Comment: woah, I hadn't noticed 11 questions and 0% accept!

Comment: This poster has just one question which doesn't end in at least two '?'.

Comment: @Martin  I want to get the message of a chat room (3rd party) with get updates every time.

Comment: Would this be a better question for ServerFault?

Comment: http://www.mywebcron.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just install linux.

Comment: You do when you install linux

Comment: can we set up cron job with 1 minute frequency in Google App Engine??

Comment: @jereon: not really, you still need something to install linux *on*, which is (a) always on and (b) always online. Unless Ubuntu is doing free broadband and UPS, linux does not provide those things :-). I have in effect a fixed IP address at home, but I still host my domain on a server somewhere (in London, I think. Could be wrong).

Comment: friends, I'm going to use http://www.setcronjob.com
but I gives cron job of 5 minutes interval for free accounts :(
Anyways, i'm happy with it.

Thank you all for your suggestions :)

Comment: How exactly will a maintaining a linux server be *easier* for someone who's decided they can't follow the GAE cron docs?

Comment: @wrt, well, I´ve never read the java SDK and I doubt that I will understand anything (don´t know java...), but I think installing  for example Ubuntu and some cronjobs is pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 3):

If this is a java app, then you can use [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/), right? This way you can control what to do when the job fails (like cleaning up certain resources, sending emails, etc).

Comment: My understanding is that Quartz won't run on GAE since it relies on threads and creating new threads is not allowed in the App Engine.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to use a service like [setcronjob.com](http://www.setcronjob.com).

This lets you specify a URL that will be triggered periodically (according to the cron pattern you choose).

Of course, you still need to have a server somewhere to host the URL and implement the actual task there.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in App Engine - see the [cron docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron.html) for details. In order to provide any more specific help, we'd need to know what you want that cron job to do, precisely.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar need. Ended up testing a whole bunch of scheduling services. Check out cronservice.co.uk/new/,
setcronjob.com or mywebcron.com. I ended up using the scheduler.codeeffects.com because of their set of features and the interface. Google for others, there are tons services like this. Most are free or give free stuff. Sorry for the late reply, but I thought this might help.

Answer (score 0):

[To schedule a job in Java, use cron.xml](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron.html)

[Python uses the more terse cron.yaml format](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron.html).

In both cases, it's actually quite easy to use, you can schedule jobs, with the following actual description and Google App Engine will understand what it means:

```
every 12 hours
every 5 minutes from 10:00 to 14:00
2nd,third mon,wed,thu of march 17:00
every monday 09:00
1st monday of sep,oct,nov 17:00
every day 00:00
```